# WebLogic Server 12.2.1.0.0 + Primefaces Issue

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, primefaces, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

I'm trying to use Weblogic **12.2.1.0.0** with a **Java EE7** application and is not working when I deploy directly from eclipse, it works just when I export the EAR and deploy manually using the GUI interface of the server (http://localhost:7001/console/). I've tested with Eclipse Mars.1, Mars.2 and Neon.

The problem occurs when I add the Primefaces (5.3/6.0) dependency in two cases:

- If I remove the **beans.xml**, the cdi stops working;
- With the **beans.xml**, I get "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListener" and the deployment doesn't happen.

Some more informations:

- This problem occurs with a regular Web Application too;
- If I choose the option "publish as an exploded archive" in the server's configuration, the regular Web Application works, but in the EAR I get "CDI deployment failure:WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name test resolves to beans..."

I think something in the Oracle Eclipse Plugin is messing up the deployment.

Please, help me to solve this issue!!

Comment: Hello there, probably is this one helpful for you? https://community.oracle.com/thread/3583447?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Hello @chaeschuechli, thanks for answering! What I've done so far:

- Downloaded the oepe-12.2.1.0 from [link] (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-1221-2740834.html);
- Downloaded the oracle basic-web-app archetype acording to this [link] (http://danielveselka.blogspot.com.br/2016/01/using-maven-to-create-ejb-project-on.html);

This application works well if a don't add the primefaces dependency. When I did, I got the same error. I've added "prefer application packages" in my weblogic.xml with no success.

Comment: Probably there are two imported JARs which contains the class `AsyncSupportListener` and now you mix them up. Check your maven tree if there are some unneeded (transitive?) dependencies
EDIT: What is the scope of your Primefaces Dependency? Runtime?
EDIT 2: Check your CDI bean names. Is there possibly a duplicate naming?

Comment: @chaeschuechli please, get this ear sample that I've made [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/sample-ear-java-ee-7-weblogic/code/HEAD/tree/).
The scope of the primefaces dependency is compile (default). About the CDI bean names, I have just one bean on this project. I've tested on Netbeans 8.1 and building with maven command line and it worked. The problem happens just with Eclipse.

Comment: Is your sample project working? If so, where are the differences? Have you checked your maven tree if there are duplicate dependencies?
As far as I remember, we've set the Primefaces dependency always on runtime or provided... just give it a try. Although, do you insist on Eclipse? Otherwise, simply use Netbeans...